# R ggplot scale_fill_gradient2 on histogram vs dotplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I'm in ggplot2 applying `scale_fill_gradient2` on single variable.  `geom_histogram()` is my default approach, but I'd like to use `geom_dotplot()`.  When I widen my x-axis, the fill on the histogram maps to my axis limits (which is desired), but when plotting the same data using dotplot, the fill maps to the min/max of the data regardless of the x-axis limits.  Sample Code:

```
### Use the Iris Data
df <- iris

### Basic ggplot setup
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=Sepal.Length)) 


## Histogram -- fill scales with my axis limits (desired)
p + geom_histogram(color="black",
aes(fill = ..x..)) +
scale_x_continuous(limits=c(2,10))+
scale_fill_gradient2(
    low = "blue", high = "red",
    mid = "white", midpoint=6)
```

[image: Historgram with properly-scaled fill]

In other words, **the fill scale matches the scale_x_continuous command** and produces the fill result I desire.  However, change the word "histogram" to "dotplot" (and nothing else), and the fill scale sticks purely with the min/max of the data.  What I want is the dotplot with the histogram fill.

```
### Dot Plot -- fill scales purely with min/max of data
### I want the same shading as in the histogram
p + geom_dotplot(color="black",
aes(fill = ..x..)) +
scale_x_continuous(limits=c(2,10))+
scale_fill_gradient2(
    low = "blue", high = "red",
    mid = "white", midpoint=6
```

[image: Dotplot with min-max fill scale]

Ultimately, the goal here is to have the dotplot fill/scale match that of the histogram.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `limits` in `scale_fill_gradient2`:

```
p + geom_dotplot(color="black",
aes(fill = ..x..)) +
scale_x_continuous(limits = c(2, 10))+
scale_fill_gradient2(
    low = "blue", high = "red",
    mid = "white", midpoint = 6, 
    limits = c(2, 10))
```

[image]